# I have got this exception "org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionTerminatedException" while executing Cypher query using Neo4j Unmanaged server extension

Tags: neo4j

**I have added the complete trace below:**

> org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionTerminatedException: The transaction has
>   been terminated. Retry your operation in a new transaction, and you
>   should see a successful result. Transaction has seen state which has
>   been invalidated by applied updates while transaction was active.
>   Transaction may succeed if retried. at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:77)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:106)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:114)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.get(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:65)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager$NodeActionsImpl.statement(NodeManager.java:82)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:454)
>   ~[neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0,16a782b42d76ca37db72958eb2565cf6aa671a29]
>   at
>   com.hs.haystack.graph.service.helper.mapper.ExtractNodeData.getContextCard(ExtractNodeData.java:128)
>   ~[server.graph-1.1.2.0.jar:?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Cypher transaction executes using a [READ_COMMIT isolation level](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/transactions/#transactions-isolation). A transaction (T1) can read some data (D) from the DB into memory, and then perform some processing based on D. However, some other transaction (T2) could have committed a change to the same data (in the DB) *after* T1 had read D into memory but before T1 attempted to commit its own changes. If neo4j detects, at commit-time, that the processing done by T1 was based on stale data, it will throw `TransactionTerminatedException`with that error message.

Now, since the exception was caused by a race condition between T1 and T2 (and both have now finished), it is very probable that a retry of your Cypher query will succeed.

To avoid this situation, you might want to prevent concurrent neo4j transactions (that can touch the same data), or [write lock](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/transactions/#_lost_updates_in_cypher) the data that your query reads.